# how to call a website aspx project in one folder from an MVC project from a cshtml, controller method or javascript within mvc project

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller, razor, web-testing

I have an aspx website project folder. I converted it to a web application. However, the web app dll is empty because aspx files seem to run at runtime, therefore the web app dll is empty. That’s one reason why.
So, I am trying to use the website project to where the aspx files live. This website project folder has its own web.config. The website project was setup around 2013, and it has lots of folders.
I believe the best way to access these website project aspx files from the MVC project is to use javascript, controller methods or cshtml?
I think the issue is that these two projects have there own start URL’s. The MVC project has this URL http://localhost:51712/ and the website project has a URL of “ http://localhost:58150  “.
I get messages that seem to say, the website folder aspx file cannot be found.
I tried these in my controller method :

```
 public EmptyResult ShowMBStest()
   {
   // Process.Start("http://MBSAnalysis/MbsTest.aspx");
   //          Process.Start("MBSAnalysis/MbsTest.aspx");
            // ~/MBSAnalysis/MbsTest.aspx
            // interesting  Response.Redirect("http://localhost:58150/MBSAnalysis/MbsTest.aspx", true);
            Response.Redirect("~/MBSAnalysis/MbsTest.aspx", true);
            // http://localhost:51712/MBSAnalysis/MbsTest.aspx
            return new EmptyResult();
        }
```

I tried some things in my cshtml and javascript. But I thought that I would try to ask you folks for the best way to go about this.

Thanks for any suggestions or advice.